# How can capitalize first letter if string starts with special character in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    String patternString = "\"[^a-zA-Z\\s]]+\"";
    String s = WordUtils.capitalizeFully("*tried string", patternString.toCharArray());
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

I want to capitalize first letter of each word. I use `WordUtils` function. And my string has special characters like `'*'`, -  etc. How can I use regex with `capitalizeFully` function?

Comment: What is the required output for "*tried string" ?

Comment: *Tried String is the required output @AbleJohnson

Comment: `Character.toTitleCase` is ultimately what is called in order to capitalize the characters, and it is called after any character found in the `delimiters` parameters in `capitalizeFully(String str, final char... delimiters)`.  We need to know if you want capitalization after every special character (i.e. just make them all delimiters), or if there are other rules you wish to apply.  For example what should `st*ring st*ring *st*ring` look like?

Comment: For example : "*string 123try -bread 1*apple" returns the "String 123Try -Bread 1*Apple". @BrandonMcKenzie

Comment: In every situation you have posted, you have only shown us what you want in the instance of an alpha char that follows a space and zero or more non-alpha chars.  What do you want to do in the situation that there is no space or an alpha char preceding the non-alpha char?  What is `st*ring`?  Is the result `St*Ring`, or `St*ring`?  Then there will be an effect on the answer.

Comment: Actually, I want to capitalize only first letter of a word. So, if the input is st*ring, the result is St*ring.@BrandonMcKenzie

Comment: @willywonka15 , take a look to my updated answer, iI used `StringUtils.capitalize`  that's capitalize the firs char in word, so i used to loop on each word to decorate the sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Mather/Pattern` and `appendReplacement`.

**Regex**: [`(?:^| )[^a-z]*[a-z]`](https://regex101.com/r/OpgBJR/4)

Details:

- `(?:^| )` Non-capturing group, match `^` (asserts position at start of a line) **or** `' '` (space)
- `[^a-z]*` Matches any **non** lowercase word character between zero and unlimited times
- `[a-z]` Matches any lowercase word character

**Java code**:

```
String input = "*tried string".toLowerCase();

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?:^| )[^a-z]*[a-z]").matcher(input);

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(result, matcher.group().toUpperCase());
}

matcher.appendTail(result);
```

Output:

```
*Tried String
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/WY9t6q)

Comment: What is the explanation of this regex ?

Comment: It fails with numbers, for example 123bread must be 123Bread.

Comment: For example : 1 ) "*string 123try -bread 1*apple"  must be "*String 123Try -Bread 1*Apple" 2) "stri*ng tr1y *-br*-ead --ap*p1le" must be "Stri*ng Tr1y *-Br*-ead --Ap*p1le"

Comment: Why `-`? And tell me what is the output of `*string 123try345apple -bread*string 1*apple-bread`?

Comment: @willywonka15 So, the first occurrence of lowercase letter? Ok now.

Comment: If the input "sTRInG" how can I make it "String" ?

Comment: @willywonka15 Use `toLowerCase()` on string. Updated my post.

Comment: your code stucks with it. I know lowerCase. but i can't make it with matcher function.

Comment: @willywonka15 Check my code with your example [code demo](https://ideone.com/Gdylzf)

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `WordUtils.capitalize` function where the , that's gonna capitalize first letter of each word in a `String`.

> Not that `WordUtils` in [commons-lang lib](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) is **Deprecated**.

*Other way using Java custom function:*

```
public String upperCaseWords(String sentence) {
    String words[] = sentence.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim().split(" ");
    StringBuffer newSentence = new StringBuffer();
    int i =0;
    int size = words.length;
    for (String word : words) {
                newSentence.append(StringUtils.capitalize(word));
                i++;
                if(i<size){
                newSentence.append(" "); // add space
                }
    }

    return newSentence.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hasn't commons.lang.WordUtils been deprecated in favor of common.text.WordUtils?

Comment: It doesn't work correctly. When I execute, the result is *tried sTring. But I want to *Tried String as result

Comment: So are you saying that you want all non-numeric characters to be followed with a capital?  This should be part of your question.

Comment: `common.text.WordUtils` also deprecated, But StringUtils.captilize is not deprecated

Comment: using `StringUtils.capitalize` in a custom method can resolve the issue, take a look at my updated answer.